# post html tags from client to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, client-server

I have a text editor on my web page. [(Jquery Text Editor)](http://jqueryte.com/)
I use ajax to send the text source (which includes html tags) to the server.
If there are html tags the server doesn't get the data. but if there are no html tags it works fine.
I tried to encode it using encodeURIComponent, but the server is too smart to accept the data.
Is there a way to send user formatted text to the server?

my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#postEditor").jqte();
            $('#btnSend').click(function () {
                var answer = encodeURIComponent($(".jqte_editor").html());
                alert(answer);
                var id = $('#msg h3').attr('id').substr(1);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: location.href,
                    data: "dt=newAnswer&answer="+answer+"&id="+id
                }).done(function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    if (result == "ok") {
                        alert("ok");
                    } else {
                         alert("problem");
                    }

                });
            });
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Let jQuery serialize the data from an object instead of creating a data string

Comment: I tried. It's not working. exactly the same.